# What is best way to merge detached entities to entity manager in JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, merge, entitymanager

I am developing web application using JPA + spring. My project layer structure is web --> service --> DAO--> GenericDAO. All classes are instantiated as singleton spring bean. GenericDAO is having instance of entityManager injected using @PersistenceContext.

My application fetch domain entities in store in http session. It needs to be reattached to entity manager using merge before I perform any db operation on those entities. I would like to know the best way to merge the entities to entity manager. Currently every time transactional method is called, I call genericDAO.merge(object).
e.g.

```
@Transactional
public void addProducts() {
   Order order = getOrderFromHttpSession();
   genericDAO.merge(order);
   // delete existing products
   // add new products
   // other db operations.
}
```

Is there any other better way to do this. Any design pattern is available for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's the best way. JPA provides this method for this reason.

```
    /**
     * Merge the state of the given entity into the
     * current persistence context.
     * @param entity  entity instance
     * @return the managed instance that the state was merged to
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if instance is not an
     *         entity or is a removed entity
     * @throws TransactionRequiredException if invoked on a
     *         container-managed entity manager of type
     *         <code>PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION</code> and there is
     *         no transaction
     */
    public <T> T merge(T entity);
```

> #### 3.2.4.1 Merging Detached Entity State
>
> The merge operation allows for the
>   propagation of state from detached
>   entities onto persistent entities
>   managed by the EntityManager.
>
> The semantics of the merge operation
>   applied to an entity X are as follows:
>
> - If X is a detached entity, the state of X is copied onto a pre-existing
>     managed entity instance X' of the same
>     identity or a new managed copy X' of X
>     is created.
> - If X is a new entity instance, a new managed entity instance X' is created
>     and the state of X is copied into the
>     new managed entity instance X'.
> - If X is a removed entity instance, an `IllegalArgumentException` will be
>     thrown by the merge operation (or the
>     transaction commit will fail).
> - If X is a managed entity, it is ignored by the merge operation,
>     however, the merge operation is
>     cascaded to entities referenced by
>     relationships from X if these
>     relationships have been annotated with
>     the cascade element value
>     `cascade=MERGE` or `cascade=ALL`
>     annotation.
> - For all entities Y referenced by relationships from X having the
>     cascade element value `cascade=MERGE` or
>     `cascade=ALL`, Y is merged recursively
>     as Y'. For all such Y referenced by
>     X, X' is set to reference Y'. (Note
>     that if X is managed then X is the
>     same object as X'.)
> - If X is an entity merged to X', with a reference to another entity Y, where
>     `cascade=MERGE` or `cascade=ALL` is
>     not specified, then navigation of the
>     same association from X' yields a
>     reference to a managed object Y' with
>     the same persistent identity as Y.
>
> The persistence provider must not
>   merge fields marked LAZY that have not
>   been fetched: it must ignore such
>   fields when merging.
>
> Any `Version` columns used by the
>   entity must be checked by the
>   persistence runtime implementation
>   during the merge operation and/or at
>   flush or commit time. In the absence
>   of `Version` columns there is no
>   additional version checking done by
>   the persistence provider runtime
>   during the merge operation.

Another way is an em.find(someKey) and copy each info that was changed. (but I don't suggest you this way). The best practices is your solution.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation of merege. From performance point of view, is there any performance impact of using merge every time? Also I am thinking of writing my own annotation which extends @transactional and one method should be called when any method with annotation is called and I will merge in that method so that every developer do not need to write merge. Will that be good design and possible technically?

Comment: Depends of the scenarios, but the performance is negligible, you remember that is always an ORM. For your second question you could used a bean mapper that perform a deep copy like Orika or Dozer, but there are many others. Any case it is a pleasure to help you :)